# Find column with unique values move to the first column and sort worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have 2 worksheets with the same headers in different orders. Headers are I.D, Name, Department, Sales, Start date, End Date and a few others.

What I am aiming to do is search through the workbooks in which the headers may be in different orders, find the column which has unique values (in this case I.D), then move this column to column A in the worksheet and sort the rest of the headers/ data in both worksheets so the layout is the same. I am aiming to do this in VBA.

Currently I sort the worksheets manually and copy the relevant column to the first column in the worksheet and check the cells match.

```
For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).UsedRange
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
        mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        difference = difference + 1
    End If

    If mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
        matches = matches + 1
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find and move the "ID" column like 1th column

```
Sub movecolumn()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim keySrc As String
Dim lastcol As Long, cutCol As Long
Dim arrcol As Variant
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
keySrc = "ID"
lastcol = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'find the last Headers columns
arrcol = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastcol)) 'Add Headers items to array

If Not IsError(Application.Match(keySrc, arrcol, False)) Then ' Check i the keysrc are into array
    cutCol = Application.Match(keySrc, arrcol, False) 'find the "ID" positiono into array
    If cutCol > 1 Then 'If "ID" column Is not already the first
        Columns(cutCol).Select  ' select "ID" column
        Selection.Cut
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "the column " & keySrc & " not exist", vbInformation
End If
Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("a2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! how would i be able to use this if I did not know the column name? is there a way to check the values are unique in that column and if they are then move that column?

Comment: who define unique value, more column can have a unique value,

Comment: i tested the code and it worked the first time, however now it keeps saying mismatch for the line cutCol = Application.Match(KeySrc, arrcol, False) any advice?

Comment: I think that ID colum not exist or is not correctly write ex "ID ". I update my code with one control to check keysrc